# Bash: Последний аргумент из выбранной последовательности в файле

Tags: shell, bash, linux

Здравствуйте, подскажите возможность сделать красивее и компактнее следующий пример на bash:

```
cat /tmp/file.txt | grep '^@P\s[0-9]$' > /tmp/file.tmp
tail -n 1 /tmp/file.tmp > /tmp/file.txt
```

в файле /tmp/file.txt надо оставить только последний набор символов по шаблону "[[[[@P](/users/1080/partyzone)](/users/1080/partyzone)](/users/1080/partyzone)](/users/1080/partyzone) число"

в файле /tmp/file.txt все что угодно может быть..например:

```
1
2
@P 1
3
4
@P 2
5
```

Comment: Показжите что в /tmp/file.txt

Comment: cat /tmp/file.txt | grep '^@P\s[0-9]$'|tail -1 |rev |cut -d ' ' -f  1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

учитесь пользоваться awk

```
awk '/^@P\s[0-9]$/ {x = $0} END{print x}' /tmp/file.txt
```

суть - пробегаемся по файлу, и найденную строку записываем в переменную х. А в самом конце печатаем х. Понятно, что там будет последнее вхождение.

Comment: `echo ab bc cd|rev |cut -d ' ' -f  1`|rev

Comment: rev вообще то меняет в строке, а не список строк. Возможно @slavutich понравиться команда `tac` - она работает как `cat`, только печатает файлы задом на перед.

Comment: да я условие что-то не понял сначала, но вообще чем tail -1 не угодил непонятно. а понял, он хочет файл переписать... ну без временного буфера тут не обойтись, я бы тогда вообще `perl -pi -e` применил :)